# Java GUI: paintComponent method in the JComponent class

Tags: java

So, first I created a JFrame object, then a class that extends JComponent with an appropriate overridden version of the paintComponent method.

Finally, I add an object of this class to the JFrame object.

Here's the code for reference:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        MyComponent comp = new MyComponent();
        frame.add(comp);
    }

}

class MyComponent extends JComponent {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
        g2.draw(r);
    }
}
```

**My question is...the `paintComponent` method takes a Graphics2D object as it's argument, but who is passing this coz I'm not.**

Comment: It is a contract between the `Component` API and the painting subsystem

Answer (score 2):

> My question is...the `paintComponent` method takes a Graphics2D object as it's argument, but who is passing this coz I'm not.

The paint system passes it in when a paint event is processed on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

In many ways, `paintComponent` is like other event handlers (`actionPerformed`, `itemStateChanged`, etc.) in that you don't call it explicitly. The system prepares the object passed to you (`Graphics` in this case) and calls it when it needs to.

Excerpts from [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#paint_process):

> [If] the paint request originates on the first heavyweight ancestor (usually `JFrame`, `JDialog`, `JWindow`, or `JApplet`):
>
> - the event dispatching thread invokes `paint()` on that ancestor
> - The default implementation of `Container.paint()` recursively calls `paint()` on any lightweight descendents
>
> [If] the paint request originates from a call to `repaint()` on an extension of `javax.swing.JComponent`:
>
> - `JComponent.repaint()` registers an asynchronous repaint request to the component's `RepaintManager`, which uses `invokeLater()` to queue a `Runnable` to later process the request on the event dispatching thread.
> - The runnable executes on the event dispatching thread and causes the component's `RepaintManager` to invoke `paintImmediately()` on the component, which [...] invokes `paint()` on the root component.

(And `paintComponent` is called by `paint`.)

Answer (score 0):

The graphics object originates in Java's GUI framework.  Any* GUI application you program in Java is built on this GUI framework.  So, for instance, you don't have to program all the code that controls what a basic window looks like, that controls how a GUI program starts up, or that controls how user interactions via peripheral hardware (i.e., keyboard and mouse) are processed.

The Graphics object is just one of many classes that come with Java and that get instantiated and passed around for you in the GUI applications you create in order to make the program a full-blown GUI program.

[*] Technically, you *could* write a GUI program that doesn't use Java's pre-built GUI framework.  But for the most part, no one does that.